# Java Will Not Compile Objects Created by Me

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I have recently been getting this Java compile error every time I try to compile code that creates an instance of a class that I have created.  I've tried compiling manually, compiling from a different location, and even tried compiling in safe mode.  I  have also completely reinstalled Java on my computer.  Here's an example of code I write and the error I always get:
**Instance creator class:**

```
public class Nothing {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Can World = new Can();
    }
}
```

**Instantiated class:**

```
public class Can {
    public Can() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

**The compile error:**

```
Nothing.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Can
location: class Nothing
        Can World = new Can();
        ^
Nothing.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Can
location: class Nothing
        Can World = new Can();
                        ^
2 errors
```

Someone who knows Java better than me has tried to compile files that I have had problems with with no success.  Also, when I run the code from within Eclipse, my IDE, it runs like it should.

Any suggestions at all or solutions would really, really be appreciated.  I would really hate something like this to be the thing that prevents me from programming.  Thanks again.

*EDIT:* I used to be able to compile the classes like this, until only recently I started receiving this error. I am compiling using an external tool I have created in the Eclipse IDE, but I have also tried compiling simply by navigating to the directory the two files are in in a CMD window and used javac Nothing.java yet the same error arises. I have also tried compiling Can.java first (which compiles), and then Nothing.java, but this fails as well.  Here is the text that I get when compiling from a CMD window:

```
02/09/2011  06:44 PM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2011  06:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/09/2011  03:45 PM               289 .classpath
02/09/2011  03:45 PM               382 .project
02/09/2011  03:45 PM    <DIR>          .settings
02/09/2011  06:00 PM                75 Can.java
02/09/2011  05:49 PM               102 Nothing.java
               4 File(s)            848 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  64,669,216,768 bytes free

C:\Users\Alex\Mindstorms\NXT\leJOS NXJ\Moment>javac Nothing.java
Nothing.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Can
location: class Nothing
                Can World = new Can();
                ^
Nothing.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Can
location: class Nothing
                Can World = new Can();
                                ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Are both classes in the same file ?, i mean is Can class declared inside Nothing class ?, if not, you must import it

Comment: @Chuck, two public classes can't exist in the same file (and if they were, he'd get an error for that), so that can't be the case.

Comment: @Chuck Birkin: Both the classes are public.  If they were in the same file they wouldn't compile, but the error would be "class Can is public, should be declared in a file named Can.java
public class Can {" or something similar.

Comment: How are you compiling these classes? If you are using `javac` to do that can you provide the exact command you are using?

Comment: I think it is worth checking if there are no unprintable characters in your source files (as suggested by GreenMatt in a [comment in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951696/java-will-not-compile-objects-created-by-me/4951718#4951718))

Comment: Do you have an output of "java -version". I ran into situation where my IDE and Windows is actually using different JDK. And maybe some JDK does not resolve dependency automatically if you don't have "import"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to have an appropriate import statement (if in separate packages), and you need to run the Java compiler from the appropriate directory. Supposing your directory structure looks like:

```
src/
   com/
      yourdomain/
         example/
            Can.java
            Nothing.java
```

Then you would need the following at the top of both your *.java files:

```
package com.yourdomain.example;
```

And you should put the following import statement in Nothing.java (technically this is not necessary when they are both in the same package, but is necessary when in separate packages, and it's a good habit):

```
import com.yourdomain.example.Can;
```

And then you would invoke the compiler from within the `src` directory as follows:

```
 javac com/yourdomain/example/*.java
```

And you could then run this program using:

```
 java com.yourdomain.example.Nothing
```

By the way, you really shoudn't be building projects by hand this way; you should use an automatic build system such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). If you create your project using the [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/), aside from giving you simple "Build", "Run", and "Build & Run" buttons plus all sorts of nice IDE features (code highlighting, incremental compilation and suggestions for fixes), it will generate an Ant build project for you.

**Edit**
Based on your updated question,... note that Eclipse's compiler is distinct from `javac`. If you installed javac using Cygwin or if you've been sharing your files between Windows and UNIX (possibly through a version control system), you may have run into an encoding issue. I would suggest resaving those files in UTF-8 and running unix2dos (or vice-versa if you installed javac via Cygwin) and recompiling. If that doesn't work, it might be worth reinstalling javac. Failing that, there's always Ubuntu ;).

Comment: No imports are needed for classes within the package.

Comment: @Damian, getting started in Java is confusing enough as is... it's not worth adding to it. It can't hurt to have the import statement, and it would be necessary if he put them in separate packages.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the code you've presented for each class into separate files (named Can.java and Nothing.java, of course) and having both files in the same directory they compile for me using the command line compiler:

```
javac Nothing.java
```

The error indicates that the compiler can't find the Can class when compiling Nothing.  Do you have both files in the same directory?

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to get that many replies so fast, thank you! Here's a few more details about everything:
  
I used to be able to compile the classes like this, until only recently I started receiving this error.  I am compiling using an external tool I have created in the Eclipse IDE, but I have also tried compiling simply by navigating to the directory the two files are in in a CMD window and used 
    javac Nothing.java
yet the same error arises.  I have also tried compiling Can.java first (which compiles), and then Nothing.java, but this fails as well.

Comment: @Alex Ozer:  Please edit the question to put the additional details in it so that someone first reading the question will see them there.  Not everyone reads the comments to the answers.  As for what is happening, is it possible you somehow got anunprintable character in one of the files (probably Nothing.java)?  Try retyping things (a pain, I know) and re-compiling.  I'd start with the `Can World = new Can();` line.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  As it turns out, I had tried setting up an older version of Lego Robotics with Java on my computer, and I had created some environment variables to go with it.  One of them was the CLASSPATH variable.  I am pretty confident that Java was trying to read that variable (which I was no longer using) to look for my classes.  Once I deleted it (and the other old variables that I wasn't using), restarted my computer, and reinstalled the JDK, everything works.

Thanks for the help from everybody though :)